# Permutation induced by multiplication of finite field elements

Tags: nt.number-theory, finite-fields, permutations

Consider a finite field $\mathbb F$. Let $a \in \mathbb F$. Then multiplication by $a$ induces a permutation on the field elements. $0 \rightarrow 0$, $1 \rightarrow a$, $2 \rightarrow 2a$, etc.

Is there any easy way to determine whether this permutation is even or odd?

Suppose $\mathbb F$ is simply the finite field with $p$ elements, where $p$ is prime. Then the answer to this question defines a function of $a$ and $p$, $f(a,p)=\pm 1$. Does $f(a,p)$ have a simple number theoretic interpretation?

Sorry if this is an obvious question.

Comment: Update, From trial and error, I believe the answer is: if $a$ is a quadratic residue $\mod p$, the permutation is even, else it is odd. So $f(a,p)$ is essentially the legendre symbol. But I have not proven this.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zolotarev%27s_lemma .